# response error while try to create a vm in Azure CLI on Linux vm

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

i tried

```
az vm create \
--resource-group my_Env \
--name newVMfromImage \
--image Machine-image \
--admin-username myuser \
--data-disk-sizes-gb 150 --size Standard_B1ms \
--ssh-key-value /path/to/my/puvlik/key/azure.pub
--verbose
```

and i get this response :

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: **-**-**-**-**. {
  "error": {
    "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
    "message": "Changing property 'linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys' is not allowed.",
    "target": "linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys"
  }
}
```

i created the key via putty and copied only the public key to my Linux VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means that your vm is already created and you try to update, but you defined a different publicKey for it, which is not supported. change the vm name or resource group or both and this error will go away

Answer (score 1):

Correct, this seems like that your VM has already been created previously and is currently in the deployment state. It is still being configured that is might be why you are not able to see it.

You might also want to have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21850).